# Show and hide dynamically generated table elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table of items being pulled from a database.  The items are laid out as follows:

```
(+) 02/04/2014
Item 1
(+) 02/05/2014
Item 2
Item 3
(+) 02/06/2014
Item 4
Comment for item 4
Item 5
```

The items under the dates are hidden, when the user clicks the (+) sign, it will show the items below it and replace the (+) with a (-) to hide the items.

The HTML roughly looks as follows:

```
<table>
<tr><td>(+)</td><td>02/04/2014</td></tr>
<tr id="id_1" class="hidden"><td colspan="2">Item 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>(+)</td><td>02/05/2014</td></tr>
<tr id="id_2" class="hidden"><td colspan="2">Item 2</td></tr>
<tr id="id_3" class="hidden"><td colspan="2">Item 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>(+)</td><td>02/06/2014</td></tr>
<tr id="id_4" class="hidden"><td colspan="2">Item 4</td></tr>
<tr id="comment_id_4" class="hidden"><td colspan="2">Comment for item 4</td></tr>
<tr id="id_5" class="hidden"><td colspan="2">Item 5</td></tr>
</table>
```

The only way I've been able to think of doing it is by dynamically generating a JavaScript function by looping through the records again and adding this `a href` to the plus sign:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle(242014);return false">(+)</a>
```

And here's a sample of the generated JavaScript:

```
 function toggle(id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 242014:
        $("#id_1").toggle();
        break;
    case 252014:
        $("#id_2").toggle();
        $("#id_3").toggle();
        break;
    case 262014;
    $("#id_4").toggle();
    $("#comment_id_4").toggle();
    $("#id_5").toggle();
    break;
    }
```

It works, but it's ugly.  Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: check your HTML markup, it is not valid and you shouldn't use IDs here

Comment: isn't TD closed before it's opened on the colspan lines?

Comment: Yeah, I threw that together fast, my bad as they say...fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add an extra attribute to identify the affected rows for example:

```
<tr colspan="2" id="id_2" date="12122014" class="hidden" >
```

then the javascript would be

`function toggleByDate(date){
    $('tr[date="'+date+'"]').toggle();
}`

more info about the useful attributes selector in jQuery [here](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

this is really ugly:

```
<tr colspan="2" id="id_2" class="hidden">Item 2</td></tr>
```

you do not open `<td>` but close it, also `colspan="2"` must be inside of `<td>`

Comment: Oops, I typed that out real fast.  The HTML I am working on is valid, will fix the post.